# ASP .NET Web Api OAuth refresh token expiration time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have a question similiar with this
[owin ticket include refresh token related data in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493688/owin-ticket-include-refresh-token-related-data-in-response)

Do you know how to return expiration date and time of refresh token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiBearerToken).This is a **Web Api** + **Owin** self-hosted.

The client is a console application (there's a html + JavaScript sample as well) which call a Web Api passing credentials.

You need to override `TokenEndpoint`:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        if(property.Key == ".expires")
             context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```